# Powershell Replace a value in a complex XML file

Tags: xml, powershell

I am trying to replace DeviceAddress value in a XML file and save it as a new file, but not getting the desired result.

**XML File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<WinCollectConfiguration version="7.3.0.41" xmlns="event_collection/WinCollect">
  <Service version="7.3.0.41" classification="Service" type="Service" module="Win" name="DestinationManager">
    <InstanceData>
      <Instance name="Software">
        <Environment />
        <Module order="1" service_name="StoreAndForwardStage">
          <Environment>
            <Parameter name="DataChunkPeriod" value="10" />
            <Parameter name="DataProcessingPeriod" value="500000" />
          </Environment>
        </Module>
        <Module order="2" service_name="SimpleEventThrottle">
          <Environment>
            <Parameter name="EventThrottleInEPS" value="5000" />
          </Environment>
        </Module>
        <Module order="3" service_name="SyslogHeaderStage">
          <Environment />
        </Module>
        <Module order="4" service_name="TCPSendStage">
          <Environment>
            <Parameter name="TargetAddress" value="0.0.0.0" />
            <Parameter name="TargetPort" value="80" />
            <Parameter name="Secondary" value="" />
            <Parameter name="Failover" value="" />
          </Environment>
        </Module>
      </Instance>
    </InstanceData>
    <Environment />
  </Service>
  <Service version="7.3.0.41" classification="Service" type="DeviceType" module="DeviceWindowsLog" name="DeviceWindowsLog">
    <InstanceData>
      <Instance enabled="true" name="SERVER">
        <Environment>
          <Parameter name="DeviceAddress" value="SERVER" />
          <Parameter name="RemoteMachine" value="SERVER" />
        </Environment>
      </Instance>
    </InstanceData>
    <Environment>
      <Parameter name="AdaptiveThreadPool.ReaderThreadsMin" value="5" />
    </Environment>
  </Service>
</WinCollectConfiguration>
```

**Powershell Script**

```
$xmldata = [XML](Get-Content -raw 'C:\Pester\config.xml')
$tochange = "DeviceAddress"


foreach ($add in $xmldata.WinCollectConfiguration.Service.InstanceData.Instance.Environment.Parameter)
{
    $add
  if ($tochange -contains $add.name)
  {
    $add.value = "192.168.0.1"
  }
  
  $add
}
```

The above code adds a new line instead of replacing. I also tried with replace function it gives me a different result.

```text
name          value
----          -----
DeviceAddress SERVER
DeviceAddress 192.168.0.1
RemoteMachine SERVER
RemoteMachine SERVER
```

Comment: The code works for me, that is `$xmldata` contains the expected result. You might get confused by your own debug(?) output. At least I interpret your two lines `$add` as such. These output the current value of `$add` before and after the change to the console. Maybe you intended these lines to do something different?

Comment: @zett42 Thank You for finding my mistake. I just added 'add' for debugging purpose(before & after) and I messed it up. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do it, is to use `SelectSingleNode()`:

```
$expression = "//*[local-name()='Parameter'][./@name='$tochange']";

$target = $xmldata.SelectSingleNode($expression);
$target.InnerText="192.168.0.1";
```

Comment: Thanks for giving me the expression to work on. As a first option, I tried to use Select-XML, but after failing to get the right expression, changed to XML Objects.

Comment: @DillyB All's well that ends well!